# How to send email using threading when new record in inserted before return a data ? how to achieve that

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-applications

I need to send email to concern employee when ever a complain is posted against him.In insertion A record is inserted and the Same details where Returned to the user .

I want to send the email using threading in C# for that,I created the email method but don't know how to use it.

CODE:

```
 public string Insert(string context)
    {
        SAM_ERPEntities entities = new SAM_ERPEntities();
        dynamic list = Utility.DesearlizeJSON(context);
        int UserId = new Base().UserId;


        int DepartmentId = Utility.IntVal(list["DepartmentId"]);

        EmpComplaint.ComplaintTypeID = Utility.IntVal(list["ComplaintTypeID"]);
        EmpComplaint.ComplaintStatusId = Utility.IntVal(list["ComplaintStatusId"]);
        EmpComplaint.DepartmentId = Utility.IntVal(list["DepartmentId"]);
        EmpComplaint.ComplaintSubject = Utility.StrVal(list["ComplaintSubject"]);
        EmpComplaint.ComplaintNotes = Utility.StrVal(list["ComplaintNotes"]);
        EmpComplaint.CreatedBy = Utility.IntVal(new Base().EmployeeId(UserId));
        EmpComplaint.ApplicantEmployeeId = Utility.IntVal(new Base().EmployeeId(UserId));
        EmpComplaint.ApproverEmployeeId = Utility.IntVal(new Base().DepartmentSupervisorId(EmpComplaint.DepartmentId));
        EmpComplaint.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        EmpComplaint.IsActive = true;

        entities.AddToEmpComplaints(EmpComplaint);
        entities.SaveChanges();


        Deliverables _deliverables = new Deliverables();
        _deliverables.NotifyComplaintDepartment(DepartmentId, EmpComplaint.ComplaintID);



        var insertedDate = from c in entities.EmpComplaints
                           join e in entities.Employees on c.ApplicantEmployeeId equals e.EmployeeId
                           join e1 in entities.Employees on c.ApplicantEmployeeId equals e1.EmployeeId
                           join ct in entities.EmpComplaintTypes on c.ComplaintTypeID equals ct.ComplaintTypeID
                           join d in entities.EmpDepartments on c.DepartmentId equals d.DepartmentId
                           where c.ComplaintID == EmpComplaint.ComplaintID && c.IsActive == true
                           select new
                           {
                               ComplaintID = c.ComplaintID,
                               ApplicantEmployeeId = c.ApplicantEmployeeId,
                               ComplaintTypeID = c.ComplaintTypeID,
                               DepartmentId = c.DepartmentId,
                               ApplicantName = e.FullName,
                               ApproverName = e1.FullName,
                               ComplaintSubject = c.ComplaintSubject,
                               ComplaintNotes = c.ComplaintNotes,
                               IsActive = c.IsActive,
                               CreatedBy = c.CreatedBy,
                               UpdatedDate = c.UpdatedDate
                           };
        return Utility.NewtonSerialize(insertedDate);
    }
```

I want that Reponse is send to user withpout any delay n email is send using threading ...

**METHOD TO CALL BY USING THREADING :**

```
Deliverables _deliverables = new Deliverables();
_deliverables.NotifyComplaintDepartment(DepartmentId, EmpComplaint.ComplaintID);
```

**EDIT :*

I found this but what if i need to return data after insert ???????

```
[WebMethod]
public bool callingmethod(int num1,int num2)
{ 
   employee emp=new employee();
   thread t=new thread(emp.method(num1,num2));
   t.start();

   return "MyDATASTRING";
}

public class employee
{
   public void method(int a ,int b)
   {
      logic...
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to create a new thread?

Comment: I and  initialize the thread to call method  but the data i want to return should be included in another thread to complete or not ?